# How to return the instance name of a class?

Tags: javascript

I would like the getName() method of SomeClass to return the instance name. In this case "SomeInstance." Is this possible to do, and how?

```
class SomeClass {
  getName() {
    return this.constructor.name;
  }
}

var SomeInstance = new SomeClass();

document.write(SomeInstance.getName());
```

**Update**

This does the trick.

```
getName() {
  for (var instance in window){
        if (window[instance] === this){
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's impossible. JavaScript has no way of knowing what you named the instance.

Comment: and why do you want to get instance name?

Comment: @suraj I don't think so...

Comment: yeah got it.. deleted my comment @AndrewLi

Comment: This is not making _any sense to me_.. if you really want something like this.. just have a property that saves the reference variable name as string

Comment: Awful homework !

Comment: `SomeInstance` is just a variable that points to an object. Since javascript is a reference based language it makes no sense to ask this question. Consider: `var x = new SomeClass(); someinstance = x; otherinstance = x` in this case we created one object, not 3, whose instance name can either be `x` or `someinstance` or `otherinstance`. Which name would you like to return? All? Even if you'd like all the instance names this is not supported at the script level. At the low-end C level implementation it is available because that is how the garbage collector work.

Comment: @slebetman good point.. OP needs to rethink the question here

Comment: If the variable is in the window scope you can get its name. See my answer, Working JS fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/gdxo0sjn/

Answer (score 1):

If your variable is in the window scope a working JS fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/gdxo0sjn/

*Note: Embedded snippet wont work due to cross domain security errors on Stackoverflow (Snippets are hosted on another domain).*

```js
function getVariableName(instance)
{
  for(obj in window)
   if (window[obj]===instance) return obj;
  return undefined;
}

class SomeClass {
  getName() {
    return this.constructor.name;
  }
}

var SomeInstance = new SomeClass();
console.log(getVariableName(SomeInstance));
```

Comment: In this case "SomeInstance." not SomeClass

Comment: Run this snippet.

Comment: @AlexanderHiggins But that's not the question is asking! Read it again. They want to get the variable name 'SomeInstance' within the class which is impossible.

Comment: Oops. Didn't catch that.

Comment: property of window.. It is a good workaround .. but as @slebetman commented.. it doesnt make sense when you have multiple references to the same object..

Comment: doesn't make sense to ask for the name of the variable you are passing either. But as long as the objects aren't the same.

Comment: I'd remove the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found this

```
getName() {
  for (var instance in window){
        if (window[instance] === this){
            return instance;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Yeah I posted that answer 11 minutes ago.